# How to display a legend when using label2rgb from scikit-image

Tags: scikit-image

I have an image, a label image and a dictionary that maps label ids to names:

```
lbl = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(traindir, "train_lbl_120_14.png"))
img = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(traindir, "train_img_120_14.png"))

lblimg = skimage.color.label2rgb(lbl, img, kind='overlay')
for id in np.unique(lbl):
    print(labelid2name[id])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(lblimg)
plt.show()
```

This outputs:

[image]

How can I get a legend that show which color is representing which of the named objects? Is ther no way to do that in scikit-image?

Answer (score 0):

There's no *easy* way to do this in skimage. From the [API documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.label2rgb), you can [follow the link to the source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.22.0/skimage/color/colorlabel.py#L74-L134) to find that if you don't pass in any colors, the [`DEFAULT_COLORS`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.22.0/skimage/color/colorlabel.py#L14) are used, and how these are cycled for label values larger than the number of colors in the private function [`skimage.color.colorlabel._match_label_with_color`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.22.0/skimage/color/colorlabel.py#L39-L71). You can use this info to reconstruct a mapping from label to color and create a [custom legend in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/legend_guide.html).

Obviously, this is brittle since it uses private function. In the future, a [contribution](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/development/contribute.html) to `label2rgb` that optionally returns a mapping of labels to colors would be useful.